# Enclose text after equals with double quotes

Tags: bash

I am getting some data and putting that into a file with a sed command

```
awk '/name_of_the_person/{getline; print}' file_name | cut -d '>' -f 2 | cut -f 1 -d'<' |sed 's/^/export FIRST_NAME=/' >> /tmp/source 

awk '/clan_of_the_person/{getline; print}' file_name | cut -d '>' -f 2 | cut -f 1 -d'<' |sed 's/^/export LAST_NAME=/' >> /tmp/source
```

and then I finally source this file to export the variables.

The problem that I am facing is that sometimes some people have multiple first names and last names and my file ends up like this

```
export FIRST_NAME=JEAN PAUL
export LAST_NAME=SMITH
```

This ends up breaking my export statement. Is there a way I can add quotes after the = till the end of the line so that it becomes

```
export FIRST_NAME="JEAN PAUL"
```

Comment: `... | sed 's/.*/"&"/;s/^/export FIRST_NAME=/'`, maybe.

Comment: @The_Lost_Avatar : You didn't show the structure of the input to your awk program, but did you consider to get rid of the `cut` commands and do the parsing of the line and outputting of the `export` statements completely inside awk (or any other suitable language, such as Perl or Ruby)? You would have then much better control on how the result is formatted, and it will probably be easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a subshell to isolate the match. This has an added advantage of taking out the `sed`:

```
echo "export FIRST_NAME=\"$(awk '/name_of_the_person/{getline; print}' file_name | cut -d '>' -f 2 | cut -f 1 -d'<')\"" >> /tmp/source 
echo "export LAST_NAME=\"$(awk '/clan_of_the_person/{getline; print}' file_name | cut -d '>' -f 2 | cut -f 1 -d'<')\"" >> /tmp/source
```

It might look cleaner with separate variables:

```
fname="$(awk '/name_of_the_person/{getline; print}' file_name | cut -d '>' -f 2 | cut -f 1 -d'<')"
lname="$(awk '/clan_of_the_person/{getline; print}' file_name | cut -d '>' -f 2 | cut -f 1 -d'<')"
{
    echo "export FIRST_NAME=\"$fname\""
    echo "export LAST_NAME=\"$lname\""
} >> /tmp/source
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed and a back-reference:

```
echo 'export FIRST_NAME=JEAN PAUL' | sed -E 's/=(.*)/="\1"/'
```

Output:

```
export FIRST_NAME="JEAN PAUL"
```